# crystal reports top 1 for group

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Hi I am trying to return the record with the highest date for each inidivdual in a database.  The fields I am working with are {Entity.TaxID} which is the unique identifer for each individual.  Each individual has multiple records and I am trying to show only the record with the largest {Tran.IssueDate}.

Does anyone know how to return only the largest {Tran.IssueDate} for a group of {Entity.TaxID}?  Thanks

Comment: * Group the individuals. 
* Sort your records by date (descending). 
* Create a running total based on individual and resetting when the individual changes.
* Suppress in details anything greater than 1.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a group with `{Entity.TaxID}`.
2. Place the `{Tran.IssueDate}` in detail.
3. In group footer take `Maximum` `{Tran.IssueDate}`

To take maximum.

```
Right click on `{Tran.IssueDate}` and go to `Insert summary`... there take maximum.
```

Comment: -1: This will only give you what the recent issue date is for that group, but will have no affect on the actual display of records.

Comment: @Ryan I suppose recent issue date should be the `Maximum` date and it will have effect on actual records if is placed in footer and supressed detail part

Comment: That still wouldn't work because you'd be missing all the other record's fields in the footer. You'd need to build on the idea of using this `maximum()` summary... one idea is that you could **suppress** all records where `{Tran.IssueDate} <> maximum({Tran.IssueDate},{Entity.TaxID})`

Comment: Actually that is the way I have tried locally and it worked for me...hence answered.. may be what you are suggesting is `correct` lets check the user response.. anyway thanks for suggesting